# пожалуйста, помогите понять, как сгруппировать значения в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Имеется исходный массив такого вида:

```
var arr = [
  {id:12, name:"john", ticket:"T601"}
  {id:8, name:"Wanndy", ticket:"T508"}
  {id:12, name:"john", ticket:"T807"}
  {id:8, name:"Wanndy", ticket:"T505"}
];
```

Как получить результатом новый массив, в котором значения свойства `ticket` собраны в подмассиве, с группировкой по `id`?
То есть, необходим результат с таким содержимым:

```
[
  {id:12, name:'John', ticket:['T601','T807']}
  {id:8, name:'Wanndy', ticket:['T508','T505']}
]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы в более однозначной формулировке, и с четким описанием задачи. Также, приводите код вашей попытки самостоятельно решить задачу (иначе вопрос будет набирать минусы, и может быть закрыт). Более подробная информация содержится по ссылке "[help]" - настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться со всеми разделами, текста там не много.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array = [{
  id: 12,
  name: "john",
  ticket: "T601"
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: "Wanndy",
  ticket: "T508"
}, {
  id: 12,
  name: "john",
  ticket: "T807"
}, {
  id: 8,
  name: "Wanndy",
  ticket: "T505"
}];

var groups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var groupName = array[i].id;
  if (!groups[groupName]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
  groups[groupName].push(array[i].ticket);
}
myArray = [];
for (var groupName in groups) {
  myArray.push({
    id: groupName,
    name: array.find(x => x.id == groupName).name,
    ticket: groups[groupName]
  });
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: спасибо большое